# What is human body's overhead when storing calories into fat, and when retrieving calories from previously stored fat?

Tags: fat-metabolism, energy

Questions:

- Suppose that someone ate an excess of `1000 kcal`.  How much of this 1000 kcal will become fat?
- Suppose that someone had a deficit of `1000 kcal`.  How many grams of fat will be lost in order to generate the `1000 kcal`?

---

#### What I've done so far

I found that [each gram of fat contains `9 kcal`](https://www.nal.usda.gov/legacy/fnic/how-many--are-one-gram-fat-carbohydrate-or-protein). So, a naive solution would be:

- An excess of `1000 kcal` will become `1000/9 = 111.11... g` of fat.
- A deficit of `1000 kcal` will cause the loss of `1000/9 = 111.11... g` of fat.

This is naive, because it ignores that the body itself requires some calories for simply converting excess calories to fats, or for converting fats back to calories.

[In Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-efficient-is-the-human-body-at-converting-unburned-calories-to-fat), I found someone claiming that such conversion has a `20%` overhead for each direction.  So, if I understand his answer, the better answer is:

- An excess of `1000 kcal` will spend `1000*.2 = 200 kcal` as calorie-to-fat conversion overhead, leaving us with `1000-200=800 kcal` that is going to be stored as fat.  Since each fat gram contains `9 kcal`, we will eventually store `800/9 = 88.88... g` of fat from the `1000 kcal` excess.
- Likewise, a deficit of `1000 kcal` will also have a `20%` overhead.  So, to get `1000 kcal`, the body will have to burn enough fat that gives `1000 * 1.2 = 1200 kcal`, which is `1200 / 9 = 133.33... g` of fat.

But, the problem with this answer is two folds:

1. It assumes that the overhead is `20%`.  I couldn't find a study for this.
2. It assumes that the overhead is symmetrical so that calorie-to-fat's overhead equals fat-to-calorie's overhead.  I couldn't find a study to claim this symmetry.